# GDB breaking at unwanted position

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

When I place a breakpoint at a certain function, and type run, function parameters aren't correct.
Example:

```
(gdb) break add_numbers
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1149: file program.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/aleksandar/Desktop/program 

Breakpoint 1, add_numbers (n1=21845, n2=1431654909) at program.c:4
4   {
```

I expect it to say n1=5, n2=6 instead of n1=21845, n2=1431654909.
Everything works fine, program gives correct output, but dont know why parameters aren't right when gdb breaks at function add_numbers

I'm new to debugging with GBD. Can someone explain?

Here is C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add_numbers(int n1, int n2)
{
    int sum = n1 + n2;
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    int y = 6;
    int suma = add_numbers(x,y);
    printf("Suma je %d\n", suma);
    return 0;
}
```

Disassembly output:

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function add_numbers:
=> 0x0000555555555149 <+0>: endbr64 
   0x000055555555514d <+4>: push   %rbp
   0x000055555555514e <+5>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555555151 <+8>: mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555154 <+11>:    mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555157 <+14>:    mov    -0x14(%rbp),%edx
   0x000055555555515a <+17>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
   0x000055555555515d <+20>:    add    %edx,%eax
   0x000055555555515f <+22>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555162 <+25>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555555165 <+28>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000555555555166 <+29>:    retq
```

GDB version

```
aleksandar@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ gdb -version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of the GDB command  `disassemble add_numbers` and the version number of GDB? It might be the case that GDB is stopping the program before the prologue of the function has been run.

Comment: Compiled and run it. `GDB` stops before function parameters got assigned. I doubt you ever checked it.

Comment: I posted disassemble output and version. I also think that it stops before parameters got assigned but why? I watched many people debug and they don't get outputs like me

Comment: Also, when I run the same code on other Virtual machine running older version of gdb and linux, I get expected output. Also, in older version there is no endbr64 at beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduced using `9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04` and `gcc 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04`.

This is a [bug](https://www.cygwin.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25901) in GDB, [fixed](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=ac4a4f1cd7dceeeb17d0b8c077c874f2247acbf0) on trunk (`11.0.50.20210307-git`).

You can work around it by building your program with `-fcf-protection=none` flag.